# Linq for selecting elements from list 1 that exist on list 2 by comparsion between 2 properties values

Tags: c#, linq, filter

How to extract from 2 different lists all the elements where the below expression is found

```
List1.id = List2.id && List1.CategoryId = list2.CategoryId
```

and how to do the inverse by extracting the elements missing in the main list

```
!(List1.id = List2.id && List1.CategoryId = list2.CategoryId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first case is your basic `Join` operation, which Linq supports:

```
var matchingItems = from item1 in list1
            join item2 in list2
            on new{ item1.id, item1.CategoryId} 
            equals new{ item2.id, item2.CategoryId}
            select new { item1, item2 };
```

For the second case:

```
var idValues = list2.Select(item => new { item.id, item.CategoryId })
    .ToHashSet();
var missingItems = list1.Where(item => !idValues.Contains(new { item.id, item.CategoryId }));
```

Here is a definition of `ToHashSet`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question here becomes how many more lines could you write to do the same simple thing

Comment: I fail to see what you mean.  Are you saying you could do the same thing in less code?  If so, by all means demonstrate.  Currently your first answer is incomplete, and would be much longer than this if you finished it, and your second answer just doesn't work, so comparing them isn't valid.

Comment: Your answer would be what I was looking for because those lists I've referred are not the same type in this particular situation but in your last example I'm getting a list of items that exist just on both tables. Based on this returned list can I implement a filter to get a returned list of items missing on List2?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a simple `IComparer` for your type of data and use

```
 var intersection = List1.Intersect(List2, myCategoryIdComparer);

 var notRepeating = List1.Union(List2).Except(intersection);

 var notInList1 = List2.Except(List1, myCategoryIdComparer);
```

You can implement the `IComparer` easily:

```
 public class CategoryComparer : IComparer  { 
          int IComparerList1.CompareIntersect( Object x, Object y )  {
          // do some type checks to make sure both are CategoryObject
          return ((CategoryObject)x).CategoryID
              .Compare(((CategoryObject)y).CategoryIdmyCategoryIdComparer);
      } 
  }
```

Comment: That wouldn't be able to handle the second case

Comment: Your attempt at the second one isn't right.  You need to get pairs of items such that you have each pair that doesn't have the same ID values.  That's done with `SelectMany` (you also wouldn't be able to fiter it with `Except` until the first query selected pairs).

Comment: Oh, and it's not clear whether or not it applies, but `Intersect` only works if the two lists are of the same type, even with a custom comparer.  You can't use it to join two lists that have different compile time types.

Comment: @Servy the type was not specified in the question. If both types have CategoryID the IComparer can compare interfaces that expose their Category and ID properties.

Comment: That's why I said, "it's not clear whether or not it applies".  It may be an issue, and it may not be.  It's an issue that you can ignore entirely if you use `Join` instead, given that this is, conceptually, the very definition of an inner join.

Comment: @Servy also the question doesn't ask for pairs but for sets of elements, so the 'inverse' will be correct

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `join` clause, although it would require you to initialize a number of anonymous types.

```
var result = (from l1 in list1
              join l2 in list2 on new {l1.Id, l1.Category} 
              equals new {l2.Id, l2.Category}
              select l1).ToArray();
```

Comment: That wouldn't be able to handle the second case